# How can I acquire a Light Ball in Pokémon Black/White or Black/White 2?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Is there any legitimate way to acquire a Light Ball in *Pokémon Black*, *White*, *Black 2* or *White 2*?

Wild Pikachu can be found carrying a Light Ball, but no Pikachu are encountered in *Pokémon Black/White* or *Black/White 2*. Pikachu can be transferred over from an earlier game (e.g. *Pokémon Platinum*), but items cannot. According to Bulbapedia, the Light Ball doesn't appear on any Dream World route or in the game *Pokémon Dream Radar*, and the Treasure Hunter on Route 13 doesn't give out Light Ball.

Is the Light Ball event-only in Gen V, or is there another way to find it without cheating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your research into the depths of Bubapedia has answered your own question, there are few ways to obtain a Light Ball. [Serebii's ItemDex](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/lightball.shtml) lists a 1% chance in B/W or 5% chance in B2/W2 for wild Pikachu to hold a Light Ball, but as you said, there is nowhere to (legitimately) encounter them.

Outside of events, there does indeed seem to be no way to obtain a Light Ball in gen 5. However, you could try browsing the GTS, although finding a Pichu/Pikachu/Raichu holding the desired item is probably unlikely enough without the fact that if you do manage to find one, it will probably be for an unreasonable or unobtainable request. Your best bet for obtaining one is probably to join a trading forum.

Answer (score -3):

No answer to how to get a light ball.
Same as above answers but i did happen to get one in black.
Buy an Action replay and use a code to get one light ball and nothing else cheaters. (Well, mayby walk through walls, or lvl 100 pokemon, or rare candies, snicker snicker)

Comment: Advising someone to cheat is not a valid answer.

Answer (score -3):

you could just use theif on reds pikachu in the pwt

Comment: Items obtained by Thief (and related moves) in online battles and single-player competitive environments (PWT, Battle Tower, etc) are not retained by the player after the battle has concluded.